# Using AWS CDK, how can I set the oathToken for source in code pipeline, to pull sourcecode from GitHub, without using Secret Manager service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, oauth, pipeline, aws-cdk

I am using CDK to set up code pipelines in AWS. The pipeline stage needs to download the source code from github so uses an oauth token to authenticate the request.  I would like to be able to access the token from AWS Parameter Store and **NOT** from AWS Secret Manager when setting the value in the stage of the pipeline.

There are plenty of examples using Secret Manager to do this. However there are no examples using the Parameter Store or hardcoding the token in plain text within the CDK project.

We are using typescript with CDK 1.3.0.

I have tried storing the token in the Parameter Store. When storing as a secure String you need to additionally specify the version when retrieving the value.  However I cannot then cast to a `SecretValue` that is required to set `oauthToken` property in the pipeline stage.

Get the value from the Parameter Store ..

```
    // get the secureString 
    const secureString = ssm.StringParameter.fromSecureStringParameterAttributes(construct,'MySecretParameter', {
      parameterName: 'my-secure-parameter-name',
      version: 1,
     });
```

I need to cast the `secretString` to a `CDK.SecretValue` to then use it to set the `oauthToken`. I cannot see how to do this.

```
  const sourceAction = new codepipelineactions.GitHubSourceAction({
      actionName: 'Source',
      owner: owner,
      repo: repository,
      oauthToken: githubOAuthAccessToken,
      output: sourceOutput,
      branch: branch,
      trigger: codepipelineactions.GitHubTrigger.WEBHOOK,
    });
```

The CDK documentation says that is is advisable to store tokens in Secret Manager.
"**It is recommended to use a Secret Manager *SecretString* to obtain the token**"

It does not say that tokens cannot be retrieved from other sources and used. I would be grateful if the situation could be clarified and if anyone stores tokens outside Secrets Manager and is still able to use them to set the Token in the source stage of a pipeline.

Comment: I see in the docs, that there is a static method on the SecretValue class that allows you to get items from a System Manager Parameter: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/typescript/api/core/secretvalue.html#core_SecretValue_ssmSecure - Per GitHub - this exists in 1.3.0 - https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/v1.3.0/packages/%40aws-cdk/core/lib/secret-value.ts

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cdk.SecretValue.ssmSecure` or `cdk.SecretValue.plainText`:

```ts
oauthToken: cdk.SecretValue.ssmSecure('param-name', 'version');
// OR
oauthToken: cdk.SecretValue.plainText('oauth-token-here');
```

From the doc for `plainText`:

> **Do not use this method for any secrets that you care about.** The only reasonable use case for using this method is when you are testing.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer by @jogold does partially work. However, at the time of this writing `SecretValue.ssmSecure` is not supported by Cloudformation and you will get an error such as: `FAILED, SSM Secure reference is not supported in:` .

There is an open issue on the CDK roadmap: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/227. The plaintext option is not truly viable as the secret will be exposed in CFN template.